# Dired ranger not working loading it with use-package

Tags: use-package

I added the package `dired-ranger` using `use-package`, but when I open a folder with dired `C-x d` , I see the regular single panel instead of the two or three panels from `dired-ranger`.

I'm loading the package like this:

```lisp
;; --- Dired Ranger ---
;; Loads dired-ranger
(use-package dired-ranger
  :ensure t
  :bind (:map dired-mode-map
              ("W" . dired-ranger-copy)
              ("X" . dired-ranger-move)
              ("Y" . dired-ranger-paste))
  ;; C-u W  to keep adding files to the ring
  
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dired-ranger` doesn't provide a multi-column view. If you want that you should try [ranger.el](https://github.com/ralesi/ranger.el). Instead `dired-ranger` provides some helpful functions for copy and pasting as you can see from the [description](https://github.com/Fuco1/dired-hacks#dired-ranger).

```
;; --- Ranger ---
Loads ranger
(use-package ranger
   :ensure t
  
   )
```